# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController modalTransitionStyle]:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, exception

i used the following code to display my image picker controll.

```
IPopoverController *popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myImagePicker] retain];


[self presentModalViewController:popoverController animated:YES];
```

but there is a error that shows

> working with image view[14335:207] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIPopoverController
>   modalTransitionStyle]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x6415950'.

can any one help me please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this...

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Or one of the other present methods, check the Apple docs.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot use UIPopoverController to present it as a modal one. Please try using UIViewController instead.

You probably will need to subclass it and either load it from some nib or create its view content manually in `loadView` method.

Comment: just tell me how can i add a image picker control in my ipad application

Comment: @Sharmain: you should create a new UIViewController with a connected xib file in which you should put your image picker or whatever you want. It is hard to answer your question with more details - I do not know your requirements.

Comment: my requirement is need to display multiple images in a small view on a button click

Comment: images count may change each time

Comment: @Sharmain: should your view be displayed like http://casualuniverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/popover_flatten.png? Or should it be fullscreen? In the first case you may want to use UIPopoverController, otherwise you may want to do as I answered.

Comment: remember i need a ipad based app

Comment: first case but not in toolbarbutton.need to do with a seperate button

Comment: @Sharmain: then you should try a solution in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292287/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsinvalidargumentexception-reason/6292334#6292334

Comment: @Sharmain: you should try [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; . This is a code from another answer on this page :-). It will help you.

Comment: @Sharmain: sender means some controll from which you want to show your popover (which an arrow points to).

Comment: i think sende3r will be a barbuttonitem

Comment: -[UIRoundedRectButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x613adb0'

Comment: @Sharmain: you're correct - it is Simon Lee's answer which I wrote you about :-).

Comment: @Sharmain: please provide a call stack at least